# Java SWT - Default Selection unusable on MacOS?

Tags: java, swt

I have a somewhat simple SWT Application which creates a TrayIcon. The TrayIcon is supposed to reacht to Selection Events (single left click), MenuDetect events (single right click) and a DefaultSelection event (double left click).

While this works fine using Windows, under MacOS only the Selection and MenuDetect events work. The DefaultSelection event does only work if you are spamming the Tray Icon like a maniac and even then not reliably - completely unusable.

The (shortened) code used is

```
Display display = Display.getDefault();
Shell shell = new Shell(display);
Tray tray = display.getSystemTray();
final TrayItem item = new TrayItem(tray, SWT.NONE);

item.addListener(SWT.Selection, event -> showMenu());
item.addListener(SWT.MenuDetect, event -> showContextMenu());
item.addListener(SWT.DefaultSelection, event -> quickAction());
```

Is there any way to properly do this? I tried to write my own Listener for a doubleclick event, but because it is a TrayItem, I cannot add a MouseListener so I cannot stop the first function which was fired before the second one.
Any idea is appreciated!

Comment: This works fine for me on macOS 13.6 with SWT 4962r3 from Eclipse 4.29 (2023-09)

Comment: I do get both Selection and DefaultSelection events for double click. I also note that none of the standard Mac items on the tray support double click so I don't think it is something a Mac user would expect.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for the quick reply. If you want to check the full source, you can find it here:
https://github.com/klibio/EclipseInstallationManager/blob/main/eim.tray/src/tray/impl/TrayApplication.java

I want to keep the set of features for this programm completely the same for all platforms. As the double click "quickaction" feature is relatively important I want to enable Mac users to have this feature too.

If you have any hints on why this doesnt work properly for me, I would appreciate that greatly. (You could even download the latest release and try it out yourself)

Comment: Sorry, but I am not going to do that. This is all very non-standard for a Mac app. The standard behaviour for icons on the Mac Menu Bar is to display a menu on left click, possibly with an extended menu if the ⌥ (Option Key) is held down. No right click action, no double click action.

Comment: @greg-449 I can understand that. How would I react to the Option Key + Left click event then? A quick google search did not result in any valuable information.

Comment: `(event.stateMask & SWT.ALT) != 0` tests the Option key being pressed in the selection listener.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks again, I'll try and rethink the Tray Icon Menus for MacOS. Maybe I will add the possibilities to the extended menu.